# How to "inject" traits to base type classes to use them in generic type methods with traits

Tags: scala, generics, traits

Okay, maybe I am tackling the whole thing the wrong way, but I need help, I can't find a solution.
I am working on wrapping up a Redis client implementation for my own use in Scala.
So I want to have a class called `RedisListClient[T]` which will internally handle all things, and I just have a `List[T]`to work with.

Now I have a factory creating such a client in the following way:

```
def createRedisListClient[T <: ByteStringFormattable](name: String): RedisListClient[T] = {
  new RedisListClient[T](name)
}
```

Where the generic type has to include the trait `ByteStringFormattable`. That's needed cause the redis client has to internally serialize the objects to a ByteString, and has to be able to do that backwards.

The needed trait is as easy as

```
trait ByteStringFormattable {
  type T
  val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T]
}
```

So I got it all working for a custom class. Let's say a ScoreModel, where scores can be saved.

```
class ScoreModel(userId: String, score: Long, scoreText: Option[String] = None) extends ByteStringFormattable {
  override type T = ScoreModel

  override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T] = new ByteStringFormatter[T] {
    override def serialize(data: T): ByteString = ByteString(s"$userId#$score#$scoreText")

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): T = {
      val split = bs.utf8String.split("#", 2)
      new ScoreModel(split(0), split(1).toLong, split.lift(2).map(s => Some(s)).getOrElse(None))
    }
  }
}
```

The real important question for me is now, how will I be able to use `createRedisListClient[String]("myName")`?
I mean `String` does not implement the trait `ByteStringFormattable`.

I tried using implicit conversions like this:

```
implicit def fromString(s: String): SerializableString = new SerializableString(s)
implicit def toString(sws: SerializableString): String = sws.get

implicit class SerializableString(string: String) extends ByteStringFormattable {
  override type T = String

  val get = string

  override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T] = new ByteStringFormatter[String] {
    override def serialize(data: String): ByteString = ByteString(data.getBytes("UTF8"))

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): String = bs.utf8String
  }
}
```

But that doesn't help. The Scala compiler sees the type String for that function call, checks if it uses the trait, and fails.

So, is there any possibility that I can use the function call with basic types like `String`, `Int` and Co with some implicit stuff, or do I really have to build Wrapper classes like the `SerializableString` in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest change from what you have to working code is to use a *view bound* instead of the bound you have now. A view bound would assert that there's some sort of implicit conversion from `T` to `ByteStringFormattable`, which covers the case where `T` is a subclass but also covers the case you have there with `String`.

However, before we do that I think a bit of re-arrangement is in order. Specifically, I think that your definition of `ByteStringFormattable` is a problem, because there's no connection between the type being converted and the `ByteStringFormattable`. As is, right now you could write this and it would compile even though it's pretty wrong:

```
class ScoreModel(userId: String, score: Long, scoreText: Option[String] = None) extends ByteStringFormattable {
  override type T = String

  override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T] = new ByteStringFormatter[T] {
    override def serialize(data: String): ByteString = ByteString(data.getBytes("UTF8"))

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): String = bs.utf8String
  }
}
```

That is, right now you don't have a type guarantee that the `ByteStringFormatter` returned will be a formatter for the correct class.

Therefore, I would redefine `ByteStringFormattable` as:

```
trait ByteStringFormattable[T] {
  val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T]
}
```

Now then, here's something I wrote up that compiles doing what you want with a view bound. But keep reading, since view bounds are deprecated in Scala 2.11 and so I show the better, non-deprecated way later (implicit parameters).

Note that I had to tweak your calls to methods on ByteString to get it to compile here because I don't have redis's ByteString sitting around, and had to use the one from `com.google.protobuf`.

```
class RedisListClient[T <% ByteStringFormattable[T]](val name: String) {

}

trait ByteStringFormatter[T] {
  def serialize(data: T): ByteString
  def deserialize(bs: ByteString): T
}

trait ByteStringFormattable[T] {
  val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T]
}

class ScoreModel(userId: String, score: Long, scoreText: Option[String] = None) extends ByteStringFormattable[ScoreModel] {
  override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] = new ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] {
    override def serialize(data: ScoreModel): ByteString = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(s"$userId#$score#$scoreText")

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): ScoreModel = {
      val split = bs.toStringUtf8.split("#", 2)
      new ScoreModel(split(0), split(1).toLong, split.lift(2).map(s => Some(s)).getOrElse(None))
    }
  }
}


object RedisListClient {

  implicit class SerializableString(string: String) extends ByteStringFormattable[String] {
    val get = string

    override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[String] = new ByteStringFormatter[String] {
      override def serialize(data: String): ByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(data.getBytes("UTF8"))

      override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): String = bs.toStringUtf8
    }
  }


  def createRedisListClient[T <% ByteStringFormattable[T]](name: String): RedisListClient[T] = {
    new RedisListClient[T](name)
  }

  def testIt() = {
    val x = createRedisListClient[ScoreModel]("ClientSM")
    val y = createRedisListClient[String]("Wat")
  }
}
```

That compiles, but as I said it uses deprecated view bounds, which are in modern scala replaced by implicit parameters. Here's a way to do what you wanted with implicit parameters:

```
class RedisListClient[T](val name: String, conv: T => ByteStringFormattable[T]) {

}

trait ByteStringFormatter[T] {
  def serialize(data: T): ByteString
  def deserialize(bs: ByteString): T
}

trait ByteStringFormattable[T] {
  val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T]
}

class ScoreModel(userId: String, score: Long, scoreText: Option[String] = None) extends ByteStringFormattable[ScoreModel] {
  override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] = new ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] {
    override def serialize(data: ScoreModel): ByteString = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(s"$userId#$score#$scoreText")

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): ScoreModel = {
      val split = bs.toStringUtf8.split("#", 2)
      new ScoreModel(split(0), split(1).toLong, split.lift(2).map(s => Some(s)).getOrElse(None))
    }
  }
}


object RedisListClient {

  implicit class SerializableString(string: String) extends ByteStringFormattable[String] {
    val get = string

    override val formatter: ByteStringFormatter[String] = new ByteStringFormatter[String] {
      override def serialize(data: String): ByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(data.getBytes("UTF8"))

      override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): String = bs.toStringUtf8
    }
  }


  def createRedisListClient[T](name: String)(implicit mkFormatter: T => ByteStringFormattable[T]): RedisListClient[T] = {
    new RedisListClient[T](name, mkFormatter)
  }

  def testIt() = {
    val x = createRedisListClient[ScoreModel]("ClientSM")
    val y = createRedisListClient[String]("Wat")
  }
}
```

And that's all well and good, but if you're going to be using implicit parameters already, what you probably want is implicit `ByteStringFormatter` objects, rather than having to call `formatter` on each element. So let's rework it one more time, but with implicit formatter objects, and no formattable trait at all:

```
class RedisListClient[T](val name: String, formatter: ByteStringFormatter[T]) {

}

trait ByteStringFormatter[T] {
  def serialize(data: T): ByteString
  def deserialize(bs: ByteString): T
}

class ScoreModel(userId: String, score: Long, scoreText: Option[String] = None) {
  def toBs: ByteString =  ByteString.copyFromUtf8(s"$userId#$score#$scoreText")
}


object RedisListClientImplicits {

  implicit val formatterSM: ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] = new ByteStringFormatter[ScoreModel] {
    override def serialize(data: ScoreModel): ByteString = data.toBs

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): ScoreModel = {
      val split = bs.toStringUtf8.split("#", 2)
      new ScoreModel(split(0), split(1).toLong, split.lift(2).map(s => Some(s)).getOrElse(None))
    }
  }

  implicit val formatterString: ByteStringFormatter[String] = new ByteStringFormatter[String] {
    override def serialize(data: String): ByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(data.getBytes("UTF8"))

    override def deserialize(bs: ByteString): String = bs.toStringUtf8
  }
}

object RedisListClient {
  def createRedisListClient[T](name: String)(implicit f: ByteStringFormatter[T]): RedisListClient[T] = {
    new RedisListClient[T](name, f)
  }
}

object RedisListClientTest {
  import RedisListClient._
  import RedisListClientImplicits._

  def testIt() = {
    val x = createRedisListClient[ScoreModel]("ClientSM")
    val y = createRedisListClient[String]("Wat")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as the answer now, even though @slouc already suggested a similar thing, cause yours is more detailed and you even explained why and how. I was so focussed on Generics and using traits and stuff that I haven't thought about the amazing stuff that scala implicits can do. It's even in the redis code I already use, so I just have to extend it to my own stuff. Your way even got rid of the `ByteStringFormattable` trait, which is not really needed. Really nice.

Comment: Oh, and cause this is the accepted answer I will post one small modification I made: I am using the `RedisListClientImplicits` class just for already existing classes, mostly default types like String, Int, etc. For classes like ScoreModel I'll define the implicit formatter in the companion object, which makes the formatter automatically available wherever the class itself is available.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to write the whole code for you since you have all these Redis dependencies so it's tedious for me to reproduce, but let me explain generally.

Your method

```
def createRedisListClient[T <: ByteStringFormattable](name: String)
```

can only accept something that extends `ByteStringFormattable`. If you want it to be able to accept type T for which an implicit conversion T ->  ByteStringFormattable is available in scope, you must say so:

```
def createRedisListClient[T](name: String)(implicit conv: T => ByteStringFormattable)
```

You can also do it with syntax sugar such as [view bounds and context bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) (view bounds have been deprecated so I would avoid them).

On a more general note, standard solution to your problem are [type classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). Let me also point you at my [blog post on this topic](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-type-classes-442ae22e5342#.sz1wd78sv). I wrote it because I felt that we needed an article which glues together all this stuff, from the problem you are having to implicit conversions, view/context bounds and type classes. If you have 15-20 minutes to spare, I think it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Those articles look interesting, I'll surely read them. Guess that's much needed. The implicit conversion as an implicit looks interesting. The `=>` means that T can be converted to ByteStringFormattable? Does that also mean that I can directly call `this.formatter` inside the client? Or how would I work with it then?

Comment: Well, ideally you would write your method as 
    `def createRedisListClient[T](name: T)(implicit conv: T => ByteStringFormattable)`. Note that I changed the name from String to T. Then inside the method body you could say `conv(name)` which would return a `ByteStringFormattable` and you could invoke `formatter` on it. The `=>` means a function; `T => ByteStringFormattable` is a function from T to ByteStringFormattable. An implicit method in scope will do the trick (Scala has a subtle difference between functions and methods, but that's another story).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to call your method like this:

```
createRedisListClient[String]("myName")
```

I.e. is it important to you that the type parameter is String? As mentioned in the other answer this can not work due to your type constraint, you would have to change that to a context bound.

But is that really what you want, or do you actually not care what the type parameter will be and just want to convert String to something suitable implicitly?

If you called it like this your implicit conversions can be applied:

```
createRedisListClient("myName")
```

You have to remove your implicit conversion methods though. These methods are generated for an implicit class. (Actually, generating these methods is the only thing declaring a class implicit does).

Comment: I need the type parameter string so that I can work with the client directly. Let's say the client has a method called "members" which will return `List[T]` based on the generic parameter T. If I use the syntax from above, I can call `client.members` and work on it like on a `List[String]`. That's the reason why I want to use type parameters. Is this possible with your suggestion?

Comment: Ok, if you really need the String - your example has to many unnecessary details for me to quickly see that - then use context bounds as suggested.

Just write [T: ByteStringFormatter] to declare a type parameter with a context bound, and use implicitly[ByteStringFormatter[T]] to access the implicitly provided instance. Use implicit conversions and implicit attributes to provide that instance.

(I have to get used to that pressing return here sends the message...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the wall of text. I usually go for "give as much information as possible" when asking here, better then missing some important information. Another poster linked an article about context bounds. I will read that up. Thank you.